# Accessing CouchDB Futon on External IP

Tags: couchdb

I am having an issue accessing CouchDB via an external computer, not via the 127.0.0.1 address.

I am running Ubuntu and I have changed the bind IP in /etc/couchdb/default.ini to 0.0.0.0 but it still doesn't work, I have also disabed my firewall too so it should be connecting.

I am running a VPS on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't have changed `default.ini` you should have changed `local.ini` because:

1. `default.ini` will be overwritten by CouchDB upgrades and
2. the settings in `local.ini` override the settings in `default.ini`.

My guess is that your problem is caused by a `bind_address` setting in `local.ini` overriding the one you created in `default.ini`